# Why MySql 8 is not using index?

Tags: mysql

I am facing the following problem: In MySQL 5.7 an index worked perfectly, now in MySql 8.0.36 the same index does not work the same. Here's my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TB_MINUTA TM 
WHERE EMP_CODIGO > 0
    AND TM.MINUTA_EMISSAO >= '20190101' 
    AND TM.MINUTA_EMISSAO <= '20190131';
```

And here the TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_minuta` (
  `EMP_CODIGO` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `REG_COMPARTILHADO` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `MINUTA_CODIGO` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_NUMERO` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_EMISSAO` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODREMETENTE` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_NOMEREMETENTE` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CADASTROREMETENTE` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `MINUTA_INSCRICAOESTADUALREMETENTE` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `MINUTA_ENDERECOREMETENTE` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CEPREMETENTE` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_BAIRROREMETENTE` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODIGOMUNICIPIOREMETENTE` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CIDADEREMETENTE` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_UFREMETENTE` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODDESTINATARIO` bigint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_NOMEDESTINATARIO` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CADASTRODESTINATARIO` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `MINUTA_INSCRICAOESTADUALDESTINATARIO` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `MINUTA_ENDERECODESTINATARIO` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CEPDESTINATARIO` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_BAIRRODESTINATARIO` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODIGOMUNICIPIODESTINATARIO` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CIDADEDESTINATARIO` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_UFDESTINATARIO` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODPAGADOR` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_PAGADOR` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'R',
  `MINUTA_FORMAPAGAMENTO` int unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CODMOTORISTA` int DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CODVEICULO` int DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CODTIPOVEICULOCOBRADO` int DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CODTABELAFRETE` int DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_NOTAFISCAL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_QUANTIDADECARGA` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_PESOCARGA` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT '0.000',
  `MINUTA_VOLUMECARGA` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT '0.000',
  `MINUTA_VALORMERCADORIA` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_VALORFRETEPESO` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_VALORFRETEVALOR` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_VALORSECCAT` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_VALORDESPACHO` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_VALORTAXAS` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_VALORPEDAGIO` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_VALOROUTROS` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_TOTALFRETE` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_OBSERVACAO` text,
  `MINUTA_CANCELADA` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `MINUTA_CODCENTROCUSTO` int DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORMOTORISTA` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_DADOSADICIONAIS` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_PESOCUBADO` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT '0.000',
  `MINUTA_TIPO` char(1) DEFAULT 'R',
  `MINUTA_ESPECIECARGA` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_NATUREZACARGA` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IMPRESSO` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `MINUTA_VALORAGREGADO` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORADIANTAMENTOAGREGADO` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORCOMBUSTIVELAGREGADO` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORAJUDANTEAGREGADO` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALOROUTROSAGREGADO` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORTOTALAGREGADO` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CODCONSIGNATARIO` bigint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_NOMECONSIGNATARIO` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CADASTROCONSIGNATARIO` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_INSCRICAOESTADUALCONSIGNATARIO` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_ENDERECOCONSIGNATARIO` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CEPCONSIGNATARIO` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_BAIRROCONSIGNATARIO` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODIGOMUNICIPIOCONSIGNATARIO` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CIDADECONSIGNATARIO` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_UFCONSIGNATARIO` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_LOCALCOLETA` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_ENDERECOCOLETA` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_NUMEROCOLETA` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_BAIRROCOLETA` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_UFCOLETA` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODCIDADECOLETA` bigint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_NOMECIDADECOLETA` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_COMPLEMENTOCOLETA` text,
  `MINUTA_LOCALENTREGA` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_ENDERECOENTREGA` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_NUMEROENTREGA` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_BAIRROENTREGA` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_UFENTREGA` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODCIDADEENTREGA` bigint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_NOMECIDADEENTREGA` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_COMPLEMENTOENTREGA` text,
  `MINUTA_CODPROJETO` bigint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_SOLICITANTE` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_KMINICIAL` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_KMFINAL` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_KMRODADO` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CONTATOCOLETA` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_TELEFONECONTATOCOLETA` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CONTATOENTREGA` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_TELEFONECONTATOENTREGA` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_DATAINICIO` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_HORAINICIO` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_DATAFINAL` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_HORAFINAL` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_QTDHORANORMAL` varchar(15) DEFAULT '00:00:00',
  `MINUTA_VALORDAHORANORMAL` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORDAHORAEXCEDENTE` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORTOTALHORASNORMAL` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORTOTALHORASEXCENDENTE` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_PORCENTAGEMADVALOREN` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORADVALOREN` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_PORCENTAGEMISS` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORISS` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_QTDHORAEXCEDENTE` varchar(15) DEFAULT '00:00:00',
  `MINUTA_NUMEROREMETENTE` varchar(10) DEFAULT '',
  `MINUTA_NUMERODESTINATARIO` varchar(10) DEFAULT '',
  `MINUTA_NUMEROCONSIGNATARIO` varchar(10) DEFAULT '',
  `MINUTA_VALORAJUDANTE` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_DATAFRETE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_MEDIAKMPORLITRO` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORLITRO` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORCOMBUSTIVELGASTO` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORFRETELINHABRANCA` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_ROTA` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `MINUTA_CODPAISCOLETA` bigint unsigned DEFAULT '1058',
  `MINUTA_CODPAISENTREGA` bigint unsigned DEFAULT '1058',
  `MINUTA_DATAPREVISTAENTREGA` varchar(8) DEFAULT '',
  `MINUTA_CRT` varchar(60) DEFAULT '',
  `MINUTA_NUMEROCARGA` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `MINUTA_TIPOCARGA` char(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'R para Refrigerado ou S para Seco (Gtex)',
  `MINUTA_CODFUNCULTMOD` double DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Funcionario que realizou a ultima modificaçao',
  `MINUTA_DATAULTMOD` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Data da ultima modificaçao',
  `MINUTA_NOMEPC` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Nome do PC em que o funcionário está logado',
  `MINUTA_TIPOCONTRATO` char(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Tipo de Contrato: E para Esporadico ou C para Contrato (Gtex)',
  `MINUTA_SETORCOLETA` varchar(30) DEFAULT '',
  `MINUTA_SETORENTREGA` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODTIPOMODAL` int unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CODTIPOMODALIDADE` int unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_TIPODOCTO` char(1) DEFAULT 'M' COMMENT 'M - MINUTA  O - ORDEM COLETA',
  `MINUTA_TIPOSTATUS` char(1) DEFAULT 'A' COMMENT 'A - ABERTA  F - FECHADA',
  `MINUTA_CODCARRETA` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODCARRETA2` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_PORCENTAGEMGRIS` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORGRIS` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORDESCARGA` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CODTIPOMINUTA` int unsigned DEFAULT '1',
  `MINUTA_FRETERETORNO` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `MINUTA_PORCENTAGEMFRETESUBCONTRATADO` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORFRETESUBCONTRATADO` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CADASTROLOCALCOLETA` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CADASTROLOCALENTREGA` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODREGIAO` int unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CODCONTROLEVIAGEM` bigint DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CODTIPOSERVICO` int unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORENTREGA` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORCOLETA` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODRECEBEDOR` int unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_LOCALCOLETADILEONE` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_LOCALENTREGADILEONE` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_TIPOSERVICO` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_AGREGADOKM` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_AGREGADOPEDAGIO` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CUSTOMOTORISTA` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CUSTOKM` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CUSTOPEDAGIO` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CUSTOTOTAL` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORPORCONTABILIDADE` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_AVERBADA` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_DATAENTREGA_COMBINADA` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_HORAENTREGA_COMBINADA` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_DATAENTREGA_REALIZADA` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_HORAENTREGA_REALIZADA` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_PENDENTE` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_ISSINCLUSOFRETE` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODMINUTAORIGEM` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_QTDPALLETS` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORPALETIZACAO` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_TIPOENTREGA` char(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'N - Normal, R - reentrega e D - devoluçao',
  `MINUTA_VALORDIARIA` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_ORIGEMRPS` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `MINUTA_PORCENTAGEMMOTORISTA` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORFRETEBRUTO` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_TIPOMINUTA` char(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'D - Diaria e E - Entrega (Parnasium)',
  `MINUTA_CODSIGLAORIGEM` int DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CODSIGLADESTINO` int DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_FINALIZADA` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CALCULOTIPOPONTUACAO` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_MONITORAMENTOPORTOSEGURO_ENVIADO` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_TIPOTRAJETO` char(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'R - Rodoviario e U - Urbano',
  `MINUTA_CODAVERBACAOPORTOSEGUROFTP` bigint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CODFATURA` bigint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_NUMEROFATURA` bigint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CODCTE` bigint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_NUMEROCTE` bigint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_NUMEROSEQUENCIALMESMACIDADE` bigint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_SETOR` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_QTDAJUDANTES` smallint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CODMONITORAMENTOPLANILHA` bigint DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CODFUNCCONFERENTE` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IDETIQUETA` bigint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_INCIDEICMS` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `MINUTA_COBRAPELACUBAGEM` char(1) DEFAULT 'S',
  `MINUTA_PRODUTOPERIGOSO` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `MINUTA_PLACAONU` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODORDEMEMBARQUE` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CARGADESCARGA` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_OUTROSDEBITOS` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_PORCENTAGEMICMSLEMAR` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORICMSLEMAR` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_PORCENTAGEMIMPOSTO` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORIMPOSTO` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CODDESPESA` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_QTDNOTAS` smallint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_SMP_ID` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_SMP_NUMERO` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_SMP_ANO` smallint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_PORCENTAGEMISSDESPESA` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORISSDESPESA` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORTOTALDESPESA` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORFRETELIQUIDO` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORFRETELIQUIDOMOTORISTA` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CODCOTACAOLOG` bigint DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORUNITARIOAVON` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORFRETEPAOACUCAR` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORTDE` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_SMP_FINALIZADA` tinyint DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_FORAPERIMETRO` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_FORAPERIMETRO1HORA` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_FORAPERIMETROAGREGADO` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_QTDVIAGENS` int DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_FORAPERIMETROAGREGADO1HORA` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORAPOSHORARIOCOMERCIAL` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORKMEXCEDIDO` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_QTDENTREGASAGREGADO` int DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_FATURARMINUTA` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_FRETECOMBINADO` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODTIPOVEICULOPAGOAGREGADO` int DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_GERAXMLPORTOSEGURO` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODIGOPORTOSEGURO` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODCARRETA3` int DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_NUMEROOS` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_RESPONSAVELMETRO` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_COORDENADOR` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_DATACHEGADAMOTORISTA` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_HORACHEGADAMOTORISTA` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_DATACHEGADALOJA` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_HORACHEGADALOJA` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_DATAINICIADADESCARGA` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_HORAINICIADADESCARGA` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_DATAFINALIZADADESCARGA` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_HORAFINALIZADADESCARGA` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_DATASAIDALOJA` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_HORASAIDALOJA` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CONTROLEEXTRATOMOTORISTANAJA` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODFUNCEMISSOR` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_PORCENTAGEMFORAPERIMETRO` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_DATAVENCIMENTO` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORIMPOSTOREPASSADO` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORIMPOSTOREPASSADOCOMPRA` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORFRETEPESOCOMPRA` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORGRISCOMPRA` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORADVALORENCOMPRA` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORPEDAGIOCOMPRA` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORTAXASCOMPRA` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALOROUTROSCOMPRA` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORAJUDANTECOMPRA` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_PORCENTAGEMISSCOMPRA` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORISSCOMPRA` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_TOTALFRETECOMPRA` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODTABELAFRETECOMPRA` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_ISSINCLUSOFRETECOMPRA` tinyint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_FRETEFECHADO` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `MINUTA_VALORTDEVENDA` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORTDECOMPRA` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORTRTVENDA` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORTRTCOMPRA` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CTECOMPLEMENTARAJUDANTE` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `MINUTA_CTECOMPLEMENTARPEDAGIO` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `MINUTA_CTECOMPLEMENTAROUTROS` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `MINUTA_DATAMONITORAMENTOBUONNY` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_DATAPREVISTASAIDA` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_NUMEROMONITORAMENTOBUONNY` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_RETORNOMONITORAMENTOBUONNY` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODEXPEDIDOR` bigint DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_NOMEEXPEDIDOR` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CADASTROEXPEDIDOR` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_INSCRICAOESTADUALEXPEDIDOR` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODIGOMUNICIPIOEXPEDIDOR` varchar(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CIDADEEXPEDIDOR` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_UFEXPEDIDOR` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODAGENTE` bigint DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_NOMEAGENTE` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CADASTROAGENTE` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_INSCRICAOESTADUALAGENTE` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODIGOMUNICIPIOAGENTE` varchar(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CIDADEAGENTE` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_UFAGENTE` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CONDICOESPAGTO` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_RETIRAAEROPORTO` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `MINUTA_SIGLAIATA` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_SEGUROPROPRIO` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `MINUTA_SEGURADORANOME` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_SEGURADORAAPOLICE` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_SEGURADORACONTA` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_SERVICONOME` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORPAGARAGENTE` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VOOPREVISTO` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_DATAPREVISTA` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VOOCONFIRMADO` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_DATACONFIRMADO` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VOOCHEGADA` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_DATACOLETA` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_HORARIOCOLETA` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_OBSCOLETA` text,
  `MINUTA_OBSDESPACHO` text,
  `MINUTA_OBSLECAGREGADO` text,
  `MINUTA_FRETECORTESIA` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `MINUTA_CODRESPONSAVELCORTESIA` int DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORTA` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORTEC` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORTAC` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_GERADOARQUIVO` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `MINUTA_NAOCOBRARSEGURO` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `MINUTA_FRETECOMBINADOAGREGADO` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `MINUTA_TIPOOPERACAODORI` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `MINUTA_PESOTOTALREGIAO` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT '0.000',
  `MINUTA_RETROATIVO` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_UFTABELAFRETE` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODCIDADETABELAFRETE` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORLAVANDERIA` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORINSUMOS` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORESCOLTA` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_QTDENTREGAREALIZADA` int DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_QTDENTREGARETORNO` int DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_QTDENTREGABONIFICACAO` int DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CODBASEORIGEM` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODBASEDESTINO` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_MANIFESTOCLIENTE` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_MANIFESTOQTDNOTAS` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_MANIFESTOPESOTOTAL` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_MANIFESTOVALORTOTAL` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODGERENCIADORARISCO` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_FRETEDEDICADO` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_STATUSEMAIL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_HORARIOEMAIL` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODFUNCIONARIOEMAIL` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODMANIFESTO` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CALCULOMANUAL` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_QTDEIXOSSUSPENSOSCARRETA` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODROTEIRO` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_PERCENTUALADIANTAMENTO` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORAGREGADOBIOSFERA` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORAGREGADOINFORMACAO` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORAGREGADOBIOSFERAUNITARIO` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORAGREGADOINFORMACAOUNITARIO` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORAGREGADONORMALUNITARIO` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODCARTAOREPOM` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_ROMANEIO` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_METACONCLUIDA` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_NUMEROROTA` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_CONTAINER` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_TIPOCONTAINER` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_DATAENTRADAPATIO` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_QTDDIAS` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_DI` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_CODARMADOR` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_DATAENTREGA` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_NAVIO` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_BL` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_CODIMPORTADOR` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_VISTORIADOR` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_CODTERMINAL` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_ESTUFAGEM` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_NVOCC` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_BOOKING` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_PORTODESTINO` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_REFERENCIAEXPORTADOR` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_TARA` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_LACRE` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_MERCADOLIVRE` tinyint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_CODTERMINALDEVOLUCAO` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CUBAGEM` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT '0.000',
  `MINUTA_VALORFRETETIPOVEICULO` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CIOT_CODTIPOCARGA` int DEFAULT '5',
  `MINUTA_CIOT_CEPORIGEM` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CIOT_CEPDESTINO` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CIOT_DISTANCIAPERCORRIDA` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CIOT_ALTODESEMPENHO` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CIOT_DESTINACAOCOMERCIAL` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CIOT_FRETERETORNO` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CIOT_CEPRETORNO` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CIOT_DISTANCIARETORNO` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_TIPOORCAMENTO` char(1) DEFAULT 'G',
  `MINUTA_VALORTAS` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_VALORTDA` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_VALORTRT` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_VALOREMEX` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_VALORMONTAGEMEVENTO` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_VALORINSTALACAO` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_VALORPALLETIZACAO` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_VALORAJUDANTE_SERVICO` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_VALORKITS` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_VALOROUTROS_SERVICO` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_DATAHORAENVIOFOURKITES` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODMOTORISTAHELP` int DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CODTABELAFRETEVENDA` int DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CODREGIAOVENDA` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_GERADAVIAPORTALMELI` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_FLEX` tinyint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_ABANDONOROTA` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_CODPAINELFLASH` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CIOTCODTIPOCARGA` int DEFAULT '5',
  `MINUTA_CODCIDADEDESTINO` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_UFDESTINO` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CICLOPM` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_DESCRICAOVALOROUTROSCOMPRA` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_QTDPACOTESAPOIO` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_DATACHEGADA_DESTINO` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_HORACHEGADA_DESTINO` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_DATASAIDA_DESTINO` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_HORASAIDA_DESTINO` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_SPOT` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_KMPAGAMENTOCOMPRAMERCADOLIVRE` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODKMCIDADES` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CIDADESDESTINO` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_SEGUROFLASH` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_NUMERODOCUMENTOFLASH` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_RESPONSAVELRECEBIMENTOFLASH` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODPNR` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_VALORCOMPLEMENTAR` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_VALORCOMPLEMENTARAGREGADO` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_COMPLETARABASTECIMENTO` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_DATAHORAVISUALIZACAOAPP` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_DATAHORAACEITEAPP` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODREJEICAO` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_SHOPEE` tinyint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_QTDE_PARADAS` smallint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_LINKROTAMELI` varchar(600) DEFAULT '',
  `MINUTA_QTDE_PARADAS_REALIZADAS` smallint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_EVIDENCIA` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `MINUTA_KM_CALCULO_COM_RETORNO` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINUTA_EVIDENCIAPEDAGIO` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_IDCIOT` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODPROPRIETARIO` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_INFRUTIFERO` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `MINUTA_VALORREGULARFRETEPEDAGIO` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTA_CODFATURAREGULARFRETEPEDAGIO` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MINUTA_CODIGO`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Unique_EmpCodigo_Numero` (`EMP_CODIGO`,`MINUTA_NUMERO`),
  KEY `FK_MINUTACLASSIFICACAO` (`MINUTA_CODTIPOVEICULOCOBRADO`),
  KEY `FK_MINUTAEMPRESA` (`EMP_CODIGO`),
  KEY `FK_MINUTAFROTA` (`MINUTA_CODVEICULO`),
  KEY `FK_MINUTAMOTORISTA` (`MINUTA_CODMOTORISTA`),
  KEY `FK_MINUTAPAGADOR` (`MINUTA_CODPAGADOR`),
  KEY `FK_MINUTATABELAFRETE` (`MINUTA_CODTABELAFRETE`),
  KEY `FK_MINUTACARRETA` (`MINUTA_CODCARRETA`),
  KEY `FK_MINUTACARRETA2` (`MINUTA_CODCARRETA2`),
  KEY `FK_tb_minuta_8` (`MINUTA_CODORDEMEMBARQUE`),
  KEY `FK_tb_minuta_9` (`MINUTA_CODDESPESA`),
  KEY `index_datafrete` (`MINUTA_DATAFRETE`),
  KEY `Index_Numero` (`MINUTA_NUMERO`),
  KEY `FK_tb_minuta_11` (`MINUTA_CODROTEIRO`),
  KEY `FK_tb_minuta_12` (`MINUTA_CODCARTAOREPOM`),
  KEY `FK_tb_minuta_14` (`MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_CODTERMINAL`),
  KEY `FK_tb_minuta_15` (`MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_CODIMPORTADOR`),
  KEY `FK_tb_minuta_16` (`MINUTA_CIOT_CODTIPOCARGA`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `FK_tb_minuta_10` (`MINUTA_CODMANIFESTO`),
  KEY `Index_codprojeto` (`MINUTA_CODPROJETO`),
  KEY `FK_MINUTA_KM_CIDADES` (`MINUTA_CODKMCIDADES`),
  KEY `Index_numerorota` (`MINUTA_NUMEROROTA`),
  KEY `SHOPEE_INDEX` (`MINUTA_SHOPEE`),
  KEY `Index_CteMinuta` (`MINUTA_CODCTE`),
  KEY `MERCADOLIVRE_INDEX` (`MINUTA_MERCADOLIVRE`),
  KEY `FLEX_INDEX` (`MINUTA_FLEX`),
  KEY `FK_tb_minuta_ciot` (`MINUTA_IDCIOT`),
  KEY `FK_tb_minuta_codproprietario` (`MINUTA_CODPROPRIETARIO`),
  KEY `Index_EmpDataEmissao` (`EMP_CODIGO`,`MINUTA_EMISSAO`),
  KEY `FK_tb_minuta_codfaturaregularfretepedagio` (`MINUTA_CODFATURAREGULARFRETEPEDAGIO`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_MINUTA_KM_CIDADES` FOREIGN KEY (`MINUTA_CODKMCIDADES`) REFERENCES `tb_km_cidades` (`KMCID_CODIGO`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_MINUTACARRETA` FOREIGN KEY (`MINUTA_CODCARRETA`) REFERENCES `tb_frota` (`FROTA_CODIGO`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_MINUTACARRETA2` FOREIGN KEY (`MINUTA_CODCARRETA2`) REFERENCES `tb_frota` (`FROTA_CODIGO`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_MINUTACLASSIFICACAO` FOREIGN KEY (`MINUTA_CODTIPOVEICULOCOBRADO`) REFERENCES `tb_classificacaofrota` (`CLASSIFICACAO_CODIGO`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_MINUTAEMPRESA` FOREIGN KEY (`EMP_CODIGO`) REFERENCES `tb_empresa` (`EMP_CODIGO`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_MINUTAFROTA` FOREIGN KEY (`MINUTA_CODVEICULO`) REFERENCES `tb_frota` (`FROTA_CODIGO`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_MINUTAMOTORISTA` FOREIGN KEY (`MINUTA_CODMOTORISTA`) REFERENCES `tb_motorista` (`MOTORISTA_CODIGO`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_MINUTAPAGADOR` FOREIGN KEY (`MINUTA_CODPAGADOR`) REFERENCES `tb_cliente` (`CLIENTE_CODIGO`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tb_minuta_10` FOREIGN KEY (`MINUTA_CODMANIFESTO`) REFERENCES `tb_manifesto` (`MANIFESTO_CODIGO`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tb_minuta_11` FOREIGN KEY (`MINUTA_CODROTEIRO`) REFERENCES `tb_ciot_repom_roteiro` (`ROTEIRO_CODIGO`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tb_minuta_12` FOREIGN KEY (`MINUTA_CODCARTAOREPOM`) REFERENCES `tb_ciot_repom_cartoes` (`CARTOES_CODIGO`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tb_minuta_14` FOREIGN KEY (`MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_CODTERMINAL`) REFERENCES `tb_terminal` (`TERMINAL_CODIGO`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tb_minuta_15` FOREIGN KEY (`MINUTA_IMPORTACAO_CODIMPORTADOR`) REFERENCES `tb_cliente` (`CLIENTE_CODIGO`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tb_minuta_16` FOREIGN KEY (`MINUTA_CIOT_CODTIPOCARGA`) REFERENCES `tb_ciot_tipo_carga` (`TIPOCARGA_CODIGO`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tb_minuta_8` FOREIGN KEY (`MINUTA_CODORDEMEMBARQUE`) REFERENCES `tb_ordemembarque` (`ORDEMEMBARQUE_CODIGO`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tb_minuta_9` FOREIGN KEY (`MINUTA_CODDESPESA`) REFERENCES `tb_despesa` (`DESPESA_CODIGO`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tb_minuta_ciot` FOREIGN KEY (`MINUTA_IDCIOT`) REFERENCES `tb_ciot` (`CIOT_CODIGO`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tb_minuta_codfaturaregularfretepedagio` FOREIGN KEY (`MINUTA_CODFATURAREGULARFRETEPEDAGIO`) REFERENCES `tb_fatura` (`FATURA_CODIGO`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tb_minuta_codproprietario` FOREIGN KEY (`MINUTA_CODPROPRIETARIO`) REFERENCES `tb_proprietario` (`PROPRIETARIO_CODIGO`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

In the MySql 8:

`Possible Keys: Unique_EmpCodigo_Numero,FK_MINUTAEMPRESA,Index_EmpDataEmissao key: NULL`

In the MySql 5.7:

```
Possible Keys: Unique_EmpCodigo_Numero,FK_MINUTAEMPRESA,Index_EmpDataEmissao
key: Index_Emissao
```

If I use the equal operator, the problem not happen. For instance:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM TB_MINUTA TM WHERE EMP_CODIGO = 1 AND TM.MINUTA_EMISSAO >= '20190101' AND TM.MINUTA_EMISSAO <= '20190131';
```

in this case, both MySql 8 and 5.7 uses the index: `Index_EmpDataMissao`

Any hints for this problem?

I was expecting the same behavior after MySql 8 migration.

EDIT: If I remove `Emp_codigo` from `Index_EmpDataEmissao` on Mysql 8 I have the same performance as MySql 5.7.

It does not make sense for me, but it's a solution for the case.
Even with select's using `Emp_Codigo` and `MINUTA_EMISSAO` on the query, I have a optimal performance on MySql 8 with the index having only the `MINUTA_EMISSAO`.

I would like to understand the reason, to optimize other indices.

Comment: Test with USE INDEX and FORCE INDEX - does the index is used? if it is used - does this improves? What are the conditions selectivity? Try to renew the statistic.

Comment: The index used in your MySQL 5.7 query (`Index_Emissao`) does not exist in that DDL. The range predicate `EMP_CODIGO > 0` is _probably_ not very selective so I wouldn't expect `Index_EmpDataEmissao` to be used. Is `EMP_CODIGO` mostly `< 1`? Does forcing it actually improve performance of the query? Why are you storing what look like dates (`'20190101'`) as integers in a varchar column?

Comment: @Akina with use Index I have the same slow query on MySql8

user1191247 it was a typing error, the correct is Index_EmpDataEmissao on MySql5 possible keys.

I've edited que question with aditional info.

Comment: Without more detail, it is not possible to say why MySQL 5.7 decided to use that index. With a composite index on `(EMP_CODIGO, MINUTA_EMISSAO)` and the range predicate on `EMP_CODIGO > 0`, the second column in the index is not used as it stops at the first range. It seems unlikely that the index on just `EMP_CODIGO` is selective enough to be worth using, so the optimiser chooses to access the table data directly. This may help your understanding - [Range Access Method for Multiple-Part Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html#range-access-multi-part)

Answer (score 0):

"does not work the same" -- Do you mean "slower"?  There have been many performance improvements included in 8.0.  Some of them may actually be regressions.

Running `ANALYZE TABLE tb_minuta;` may (or may not) recompute the statistics enough for 8.0 to change its index choice.  Was 8.0 actually slower than 5.7?

MySQL has essentially no way to provide a two-dimensional index.  The dimensions involve EMP_CODIGO and MINUTA_EMISSAO .

A composite (multi-column) index works nicely if the first columns are tested with `=` and only the last one is tested with an inequality.

Your KEY `Index_EmpDataEmissao` (`EMP_CODIGO`,`MINUTA_EMISSAO`) assumes that the first column is selective enough, but apparently it is not.  Swapping the columns (either in that INDEX or a separate index) may not help because the range for the other column looks rather broad (a full year?)_

It seems `MINUTA_EMISSAO` should be a `DATE`, not `VARCHAR`.  (Changing the datatype won't help significantly.)

That table seems to have far too many columns (442).  Consider breaking it into logical groups, especially if you don't really do `SELECT *`.  Shrinking the table size will at least help some with speed.

`decimal(17,2)` -- Are the values really that big?  That datatype takes 8 bytes.

31 indexes is a lot.  (Possibly slowing down INSERTs.)  Ditto for the 19 Constraints.

Splitting a datetime into `date` and `time` is usually counterproductive.